# A unique greedy basis is symmetric

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

I have heard it said that if a Banach space has a unique greedy basis, then that basis must be symmetric.  I would like to see the proof of this.  Is there a reference for this fact?

#### Definitions

Fix a basis $(e_j)$ for $X$ with biorthogonal functionals $(e_j^*)$.  Let $(\mathcal{G}_m)$ be a sequence of maps such that $\mathcal{G}_m(x)=\sum_{j\in B}e_j^*(x)e_j$, where $B\subset\mathbb{N}$ is chosen so that $\#B=m$, and $|e_j^*(x)|\geq|e_k^*(x)|$ whenever $j\in B$ and $k\notin B$. We say that $(e_j)$ is **greedy** if there is $C\geq 1$ such that for any $x\in X$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\|x-\mathcal{G}_m(x)\|\leq C\inf\|x-y\|$, where the "inf" is taken over all $y\in X$ which can be expressed as the linear combination of $m$ elements of $(e_j)$.

Comment: It is not clear (at least for me), what a "greedy basis" and what a "symmetric basis" is.

Comment: Fix a basis $(e_j)$ for $X$ with biorthogonal functionals $(e_j^*)$.  Let $(\mathcal{G}_m)$ be a sequence of maps such that $\mathcal{G}_m(x)=\sum_{j\in B}e_j^*(x)e_j$, where $B\subset\mathbb{N}$ is chosen so that $\#B=m$, and $|e_j^*(x)|\geq|e_k^*(x)|$ whenever $j\in B$ and $k\notin B$. We say that $(e_j)$ is **greedy** if there is $C\geq 1$ such that for any $x\in X$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\|x-\mathcal{G}_m(x)\|\leq C\inf\|x-y\|$, where the "inf" is taken over all $y\in X$ which can be expressed as the linear combination of $m$ elements of $(e_j)$.

Comment: A basis is **symmetric** when it is unconditional and equivalent to all its permutations.

Comment: A basis is greedy if and only if it is unconditional and democratic (see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=g9nj7dcfNhoC&pg=PA242#v=onepage&q&f=false)).  Doesn't this imply a permutation of a greedy basis is a greedy basis? This would give your result.

Comment: Yup, that would do it.  Very easy---I should have gotten it alone.  Thank you!